# Disabling header effect in wordpress theme (Bulan)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, header

I've got a small problem with disabling a feature from a free WordPress theme. The theme is called 'Bulan" and adds a yellow glow over the header image but I can't seem to get rid of it in the code. In the chrome inspect view I can see it is generated inline when viewing the index page source.

In between header tags of the index there is:

```html
<style id='bulan-style-inline-css' type='text/css'>
  .site-header {
    background-image: url("http://upabove.be/myrdd/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/town_summer-1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  .site-header::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(204, 137, 0, 0.3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Somebody has any idea how to get around this?

Url to website is:
[www.upabove.be/myrdd](http://upabove.be/myrdd)

All the best and thanks in advance,
Michiel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find it in the code, an idea would be to override it by adding the CSS to the header and if it ends up above the CSS, then sadly you would have to include "!important" to make sure it does override the pseudo class background color. For example:

```
.site-header::after {background: none;}
```